# The method 'getProducts' was called on null

Tags: flutter, api, rest

i am trying to retrieve data using rest api from woocommerce website using flutter

this is the api for retrieve json data

```
Future<List<Product>> getProducts(String tagId) async {
List<Product> data = new List<Product>();

try {
  String url = Config.url +
      Config.productsURL +
      "?consumer_key=${Config.key}&consumer_secret=${Config.secret}&tag=$tagId";
  var response = await Dio().get(url,
      options: new Options(
          headers: {HttpHeaders.contentTypeHeader: "application/json"}));
  if (response.statusCode == 200) {
    data = (response.data as List).map((i) => Product.fromJson(i),).toList();
  }
} on DioError catch (e) {
  print(e.response);
}
return data;
```

}

this is the widget to handle the data to the mobile app

```
 class WidgetHomeProducts extends StatefulWidget {
 WidgetHomeProducts({Key key, this.labelName, this.tagId}) : super(key : key);

 String labelName;
 String tagId;
 @override
_WidgetHomeProductsState createState() => _WidgetHomeProductsState();
}

class _WidgetHomeProductsState extends State<WidgetHomeProducts> {
  APIServices apiServices;
  @override
  void initState() {
    apiServices = new APIServices();
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: const Color(0xffF4F7FA),
      child: Column(
      children: <Widget>[
         Row(
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
            children: <Widget>[
              Padding(
                 padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 16, top: 4),
                 child: Text(
                   this.widget.labelName,
                   style: TextStyle(fontSize: 18, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                 ),
              ),
              Padding(
                padding: EdgeInsets.only(left: 16, top: 4),
                child: FlatButton(
                 onPressed: () {},
                 child: Text(
                  'View All',
                   style: TextStyle(color: Colors.blueAccent),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
         _productList(),
        ],
      ),
    );
   }

   Widget _productList(){
     return new FutureBuilder(
       future: apiServices.getProducts(this.widget.tagId),
       builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<List<Product>> model){
         if(model.hasData){
            return _buildList(model.data);
         }if(model.hasError){
            print("error");
          }
         return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator(),);
        });
       }
```

i got The method error message that says

'getProducts' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: getProducts("971")

can anyone help me to fix this?

Comment: Try declaring the apiServices outside of `initState` , `APIServices apiServices = APIServices()`

Comment: Problem solved!!! Thank you very much